# Is there a way to Place a Tree Column inside of a ComboBox?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

Please help. I'm also using panels. I would just like to place my tree column data inside of a ComboBox. I was told that I may have to replace my tree column component with a ComboBox component but prefereably I would just like to display my expanded tree column within a ComboBox. Not sure if this is possible.
 I'm a bit new but I've been working on this for hours.

My code is:

```
Ext.define('TV.view.configPanel.data.GroupingTree', {
            extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
            alias: 'widget.groupingTreeNew',

            title: 'Groupings',

            // Properties
            hideHeaders: true,
            rootVisible: false,
            enableDrop: false,
            scroll: false,
            folderSort: false,
            enableColumnHide: false,
            enableColumnMove: false,
            enableColumnResize: false,
            maintainFlex: true,
            multiSelect: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            forcefit: true,
            cls: 'GridRowWithHandSymbol',

            plugins: [pToolsTips],

            // Custom property
            loaded: false,

            viewConfig: {
                markDirty: false,
                copy: true,
                allowCopy: true,
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'customtreeviewdragdrop',
                    dragGroup: 'groupingsddgroup',
                    dropGroup: 'groupingsgridddgroup',
                    isTarget: false,
                    enableDrop: false
                },
                style: { overflow: 'auto' }
            },

            // Store
            store: Stores.GroupingTreeStore,

            initComponent: function (cfg) {
                Ext.applyIf(this.config, cfg || {});
                this.columns = this.buildColumns();
                this.callParent(arguments);
            },

            tbar: [{
                xtype: 'datatabTreeviewTrigger',
                flex: TV.constants.Constant.Flex.OnePart
            }, {
                xtype: 'image',
                src: 'Resources/truview/themes/images/search-icon.png',
                padding: 0
            }],

            buildColumns: function () {
                return [
                    {
                        xtype: 'treecolumn',
                        dataIndex: TV.constants.Constant.DataTabFields.GroupingsTreeColumnName,
                        flex: TV.constants.Constant.Flex.OnePart
                    }];
            }

        });
```

Comment: There's an example of it here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/simple-tasks/index.html

Under the list header.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial problem. What you will need to do is to extend [Ext.form.field.Picker](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Picker) with a new class. [Ext.form.field.Picker] is the abstract class that basically represents an empty combobox component. Then in your new class, implement the abstract `createPicker` method to add your tree rendering/logic. A good starting point would be to look at how the [Ext.form.field.ComboBox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox) is created: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/ComboBox.html#Ext-form-field-ComboBox and look at the createPicker method there.